# C'est / Il est. Tu as vu ce film ? Il/C'était intéressant

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, oral, démonstratifs

Dans ce dialogue :

> Tu as vu ce film ? C'était intéressant.

Cependant, j'ai appris que quand on parle de quelque chose en particulier, on doit utiliser « il », et « ce film » est une chose spécifique, car l'adjectif démonstratif « ce » est utilisé.

Alors, pourquoi « C'était » est  utilisé au lieu de « Il était » ? Peut-être parce que c'est la langue parlée ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En effet cette remarque est tout à fait pertinente. Pour parler du film précédemment évoqué, il n'est pas possible d'utiliser le pronom *ce*, il faut nécessairement utiliser *il* :

> Tu as vu ce film ? Il est/était intéressant.

Mais dans ce cas il est aussi possible d'utiliser *ce* pour parler de l'expérience (*voir le film*) ou de ce qui se passe dans le film.

> Tu as vu le film ? Ce (que j'y ai vu) était intéressant.

Cette utilisation de *ce* est un peu imprécise, et n'est en général utilisée qu'à l'oral.

Comment: Remanier le deuxième exemple en "C'était intéressant (d'avoir vu ce film)" montrerait un peu plus clairement la logique interne de la langue, je pense.

Comment: Pour faire suite au commentaire précédent, dans *c'était intéressant*, il s'agit de qualifier *voir le film* et pas *le film*. Le film aurait pu être totalement inintéressant mais les conditions de visionnage être captivantes...
Par ailleurs, les formules en *tu* sont plutôt caractéristiques de l'oral...

Comment: @GAMPUB: en effet, c'est une bonne remarque et peut-être une meilleure façon d'expliquer la construction dans ce cas. Mais *Tu as vu le film ? C'est l'histoire de …* fonctionne aussi, et ne peut que désigner le contenu.

Comment: Bien sûr @StéphaneGimenez, il ne s'agit pas de restreindre l'interprétation de *ce* à *voir le film* mais de l'étendre aux deux constituants possibles...

Comment: Merci de vos commentaires. J'ai bien compris votre explication, mais si je veux dire que le film était intérresant, dans la langue parlée je pourrais utiliser "c'était intéressant"(le film, et pas le fait de "voir le film"). Je sais que c'est incorrect dans la langue écrite, mais je voudrais savoir si les français utilisent "ce" comme ça quand ils parlent dans un contexte quotidien.